# Extends Helper - Security Risk identified via SPCAF/ESLint?

Tags: typescript, eslint

*(PreScript: I was initially going to raise this as an issue in GitHub but the template recommends general questions go here rather than there, as this technically really isn't a bug).*

When we run the SPCAF code analysis framework (v.6.9.2.2802) against TypeScript output (v 2.1.4) we get the following security risk identified in the emitted Extends Helper at the top of every analysed JS file:

`The comma operator used in sequences can cause confusion what the code should actually return`

https://docs.spcaf.com/v6/SPC028904_NoCommaOperator.html?version=6.9.2.2802

(This rule is based on the ESLint rule: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-sequences.html)

This is in relation to this line in the helper:

`d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());`

It appears that the ES Lint rule has issue with the two statements being seperated by a comma rather than a semicolon.

My question is: is there a genuine security risk for these statements being separate by a comma, and if so can this be updated in the helper's emitter?

Otherwise, as per the ES Lint's exceptions to the rule about the sequence being explicitly wrapped in parantheses, could that expression in the ternary be updated to be wrapped in two brackets?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a concern in generated code as you presented here, and there are safe ways to use this, as there are safe ways of using other forms of JavaScript that cause security concerns.

There is a method to use the comma operator for indirect evaluation of code. This can also cause side effects in the code that weren't intended by the programmer, which can be easily exploited in some examples.

This error can be ignored from generated code, as it is only a possible security risk and this rule is not valid vs TypeScript.

Rules should be configured for the target language and platform. Some rules just don't apply in some environments.

Kind regards,
Hugh

[source]
I'm the lead developer at Rencore GmbH creators of SPCAF.